# Uploading an asp.net to a host (GoDaddy)

Tags: c#, asp.net, publishing

I have just started with asp.net and have created a Web Application which I am wanting to upload to my website so I can test it on something other than localhost.

I have uploaded all of the files that are output when I built the application to a folder through FTP on the web server however when I try to navigate to the aspx page I made, I get the error *'Could not load type 'MyWebsite.MainMaster'.'* which I assume has something to do with the master page that the content page links to.

I have read about something called IIS which may be required but I can't seem to find anything that explains what it is and what it does. I am using GoDaddy as a host if that helps in anyway.

Any help as to how to actually get the website running would be great! If I have forgotten any information I will be happy to share it.
Thanks!

Here is the HTML for the Master Page which is where the error is popping up. The specific line is the first one beginning *<%@ Master Language="C#"...>*.
I have not edited any of the C# files.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainMaster.master.cs" Inherits="MyWebsite.MainMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Master Page Test</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div id="headerContainer">
            <div id="headerContent">
                <h1>ASP.NET Test/h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="buttonContainer">
            <div id="buttonBar">
                <ul>
                  <li class="buttons activeButton">         
                        <a href="../">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="buttons">         
                        <a href="../about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="buttons">
                        <a href="../placeholder">Placeholder</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="buttons">
                        <a href="../contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="bodyContainer">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="bodyContent" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the MainMaster.Master.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyWebsite
{
    public partial class MainMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IIS is Internet Information Services, Microsoft's web server software. That's what Go Daddy is running on their servers. Google it.

Try running the site locally (are you using Visual Studio?) before uploading to the server.

Comment: @msm8bball I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and have tried and succeeded at running the site locally through debugging. Most of the things I have found while searching for IIS doesn't mention how to use it or whether I explicitly need it.

Comment: Go Daddy is running IIS on their servers (so long as you have a Windows host). You don't have to set that up, although you can make configuration changes. When you run through debugging in VS 2013, you're actually running a mini version of IIS. Don't trouble yourself about that though. Just make sure your files are uploaded to the server properly. See what line number your site fails on, then post the relevant code here (edit your post).

Comment: Can you post your code for MainMaster.master.cs?

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: In Visual Studio, click on the Build menu, then on Publish.  The first time, it will prompt you to configure a Publish destination.  You should publish directly to GoDaddy by using the "FTP" publish method.  Publishing this way will ensure that all necessary files are copied up to GoDaddy.

If you're still running into problems after doing that, you may be running into a Trust issue.  If you are using any additional assemblies beyond the basic .NET Framework installation, the Trust level of the hosting environment may prevent your app from running.  I believe GoDaddy's default hosting model runs in a Low Trust environment.  Unfortunately many ASP.Net applications beyond the most basic ones do not run in Low Trust, without a lot of changes.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, as he can't even get the Master Page to load before any code runs. Although the Publish information should prove helpful to him...

Comment: I found this page on GoDaddy's website: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/2531/what-trust-level-can-i-use-when-running-aspnet which states that I should set trust level to Full in the web.config. However, after doing this I received another error when trying to access the page stating that _" It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."_